# Write to a dynamic PubSub topic from a Dataflow job based on message content

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I would like to route dynamically the different elements of a PCollection to different PubSub topics, based on the content of a field. The topics are not persistent but it is assumed that they exist when PubSubIO.Write() is executed at runtime. So Dataflow should only infer their names at runtime on a per-message basis.

The feature exists for BigQuery and dynamic table names : https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/DynamicDestinations.html

Is there a way to do something similar with PubSubIO ?

Maybe not based on the message content but on an attribute ? https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/PubsubIO.PubsubMessage.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do something similar with PubSubIO ?

There is no equivalent to `DynamicDestinations` for Pub/Sub.

You'll need to know all of the Pub/Sub topics ahead of time and have them defined in the pipeline. The pipeline can be partitioned based on some value or attribute of the Pub/Sub message and routed to the appropriate Pub/Sub topic. The `Partition` transform will examine the `PubsubMessage` and determine which partition the message belongs.

Reference: [Partition](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Partition.html)

> Maybe not based on the message content but on an attribute ?

Yes, you can access a message's attributes.

Comment: An alternative is to just write a ParDo that uses the Pubsub API directly and writes to your topic of interest.

Comment: Though it should be noted, that if this is a high-volume topic, it is usually more efficient to use PubSubIO.Write() since this performs batching under the covers.

Comment: How can we do this based on a messge's attributes?

Comment: Has anybody suggested this as a feature yet in the appropriate issue tracker? This seems used. The need for it came up for me and for now I'm solving it by using a custom application that reads messages from a subscription, looks at the contents to figure out the name of the topic it should go to, and keep an in memory list of topic references that it continuously builds at runtime to publish each message to.